# memory clobbered past end of allocated block C

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I have a struct that has a BST of vertices within it (nodes called vertex). Each vertex has a char array name. I'm working on a function that gets all the vertex names and stores them in an array.

I feel like this should be working, but when testing I'm getting "memory clobbered past end of allocated block". I'm newer to C, and I've debugged a lot and can't surely determine which variable or where this is getting thrown. Any help would be appreciated!

I have narrowed it down so that I know this error is getting thrown somewhere in fill_vertices_array() once it is called from get_vertices(), but I can't narrow it down any more to a certain variable or recursion.

```
char **get_vertices(Graph graph) {
    int num_verts = num_vertices(graph);

    /* use a pointer so recursive calls won't effect incrementation */
    int *i = malloc(sizeof(*i));

    /* allocate space for all vertices plus 1 for the null index */
    char **vertices = (char **)malloc((num_verts + 1) * sizeof(char *));

    *i = 0;

    /* fill with vertices */ /* CLOBBERING HAPPENING SOMEWHERE IN BELOW CALL */
    fill_vertices_arr(vertices, i, graph.vertex);

    /* save NULL as the last index */
    vertices[num_verts] = NULL;

    return vertices;
}


void fill_vertices_arr(char **vertices, int *start_index, Vertex *vertex) {
    if (vertex != NULL) {
        /* in-order traversal, adding to array */
        fill_vertices_arr(vertices, start_index, vertex->left);

        vertices[*start_index] = (char *)malloc(strlen(vertex->name) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(vertices[*start_index], vertex->name);
        (*start_index) += 1;

        fill_vertices_arr(vertices, start_index, vertex->right);
    }
}
```

Note: In my test, I have added 8 vertices, and this has succeeded, so it has 8, each with a name. When I then run "char **names = get_vertices(graph)" I get the clobber error.

Comment: @Stargateur I've made that change, still receiving the same clobber error.

Comment: `char ***vertices` Being a "3 star programmer" is NOT a good thing. Especially if you admit you're new to C.

Comment: @John3136 I assumed that because I was altering a double pointer, I had to pass in a pointer to it to edit it directly. I've changed it to ** from ***, still getting the same error though.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `(char *)malloc(strlen(vertex->name) * sizeof(char));` => `malloc(strlen(vertex->name) + 1);`

Comment: @Stargateur Was writing up a MCVE, just tried that and it worked! Could you explain how you came to this answer? I thought I had to allocate space for each char as I was. Thanks so much!

Comment: @shplaz https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling, "The term length of a string is used in C to describe the number of bytes preceding the zero byte.[1] strlen is a standardised function commonly used to determine the length of a string. A common mistake is to not realize that a string uses one more unit of memory than this length, in order to store the zero that ends the string."

Comment: @shplaz In any program where you dynamically allocate memory, don't forget to run your program through a memory use/error checking program like `valgrind` on Linux.

Comment: strlen returns the length of a string excluding the null terminating charater.

try this:

vertices[*start_index] = (char *)malloc((strlen(vertex->name)+1) * sizeof(char));

And after strcpy
vertices[(*start_index)+ strlen(vertex->name)+1] = '\0';

And, you don't need the pointer of pointer to be of lenght "num_verts + 1"
It should be num_verts.
So,
char **vertices = (char **)malloc((num_verts) * sizeof(char *));

Comment: Also, you don't have to define i as a pointer to an int. You can define i as an int, initialise it to 0 and the address of i to fill_vertices_arr.